# bulk insert using jpa eclipselink

Tags: jsf, jpa, bulkinsert

i am using jpa eclipselink for database mysql, i need to bulk insert one list contains more than 6000 objects. But only 215 rows is inserted in the database and no exception is thrown.

here is my code

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "Cation";

    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            for (int i = 0; i < sgmlList.size(); i++) {
                // Getting the object from the list by using loop
                SGML sgml = sgmlList.get(i);
                em.persist(sgml);
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage("SGML imported successfully"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue plz.

Answer (score 3):

Your catch blog simply ignores any exceptions thrown. Perhaps you should log them so that you actually see them. :)

Answer (score 1):

JPA bulk insert is like this ..

```
 public void bulkinsertEditores(List<Editore> editories) {
try {
EntityManagerFactory emf = EntityManagerFactoryClass.getEntityManagerFactoryInstance();
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
int ip = 0;
for (Editore ed : editories) {
ip = ip + 1;
em.persist(ed);
if ((ip % 20) == 0) {
  em.flush();
  em.clear();
  }

}

  em.getTransaction().commit();
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
```